# How do I make my shared_ptr point to the specific address inside a nested vector

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, memory-address, ros

I have a vector of vectors, like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<X> > > vOP;
```

I want to assign another `boost::shared_ptr` to the nested `vector` above, and then compute/display certain visualizations.

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
boost::shared_ptr<X> tempPtr;   

if(num < vOP[refID].size() )     //  refID returns the ID number 
{
    tempPtr = vOP[refID].at(num);

    ROS_INFO_STREAM("ADDRESS OF vOP:  "<< vOP[refID].at(num)<<" for refID: "<<refID );
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("&REFERENCE ADDRESS OF vOP:  "<< &vOP[refID].at(num));
}
```

But I get an assertation failed error as `tempPtr` is not pointing to that nested `vector`.

My code works if `refID` is 0; but otherwise my code fails. Both the `ROS_INFO_STREAM`'s output different addresses.

Can someone explain to me what these two addresses mean? How do I make my pointer point to the correct address?

Comment: You should edit your question to include the `ros` tag thus increasing your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Just a thought, `num < vOP[refID].size()` may be more readable.

Comment: Thanks you! I have added it now!

Comment: What you should really do is post an [MCVE], as instructed.

Comment: The code shown is not actually using `tempPtr` for anything, so where is the assertion being raised?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<X> VectorContent;
typedef std::vector<VectorContent> 1D_Vector;
typedef std::vector<1D_Vector> 2D_Vector;
```

Then:

`vOP[refID].at(num)` returns a `VectorContent&`

`&vOP[refID].at(num)` returns a `VectorContent*`

When you print them:

`VectorContent&` will call `boost::shared_ptr<X>::get()` and print the pointer that the `boost::shared_ptr<X>` is holding.

`VectorContent*` will print the address of the `boost::shared_ptr<X>` itself.

So you get two different addresses.

If you want to get the address of a `boost::shared_ptr<X>` that is inside of the `vector`, declare `tempPtr` as `boost::shared_ptr<X>&` instead, so it is a reference and not a copy.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting two different addresses in the output because you are passing two different pointers to `operator<<` to begin with.

`vOP[refID].at(num)` returns a `boost::shared_ptr<X>&` - a *reference* to a `boost::shared_ptr<X>`.

Boost defines an `operator<<` that outputs a `boost::shared_ptr` to a `std::ostream`.  That operator outputs the pointer that the `shared_ptr` is holding.  So, this line:

```
ROS_INFO_STREAM("ADDRESS OF vOP:  "<< vOP[refID].at(num)<<" for refID: "<<refID );
```

Is effectively the same as this:

```
ROS_INFO_STREAM("ADDRESS OF vOP:  "<< vOP[refID].at(num).get() <<" for refID: "<<refID );
```

When you use the `&` address operator on a reference, it returns the address of the item that is being referenced.  In this case, it is returning the address of the `boost::shared_ptr` object itself, not the pointer that it is holding.

If you do this:

```
boost::shared_ptr<X> tempPtr = vOP[refID].at(num);
ROS_INFO_STREAM("ADDRESS OF vOP: " << &tempPtr << " for refID: " << refID);
```

`tempPtr` is a new object that copies the `X` pointer.  You will be outputting the address of the `tempPtr` variable itself, not the address of the `boost::shared_ptr` that is inside the vector.

If you do this instead:

```
boost::shared_ptr<X> &tempPtr = vOP[refID].at(num);
ROS_INFO_STREAM("ADDRESS OF vOP: " << &tempPtr << " for refID: " << refID);
```

`tempPtr` is now a reference, not a copy.  You will be outputting the address of the `boost::shared_ptr` that is inside the vector.